# I cannot parse this xml file in python

Tags: python, xml, dataframe, api, parsing

I am trying to create an API connection and response is looking like below. I need to parse this data and turn it into a pd dataframe and/or create loop to find specific information belong to tags.

Below is the code i try to run but it returns with empty list, and it looks not iterable.

Also it is not convertible to a data frame for now. What steps should I take to handle this data?

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

response = """<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<Desperados_Clientes_V2.DESPERADOSResponse xmlns="TrainsWebb_V16">
<Sdtdesperadosclient xmlns="TrainsWebb_V16">
<SDTDesperadosClientItem xmlns="TrainsWebb_V16">
<AESA>10555555555        </AESA>
<DOCUMENTO>1666666666</DOCUMENTO>
<REMITENTE>888888888     </REMITENTE>
<NM_REMITENTE>ABDULREZZAK S.A.S.                        </NM_REMITENTE>
<FECHA_ELABORACION>14/8/2020</FECHA_ELABORACION>
<HORA_ELABORACION>11:27</HORA_ELABORACION>
<CODIGO_DEST>0000000000</CODIGO_DEST>
<NIT_DESTINATARIO>0000000000</NIT_DESTINATARIO>
<NOMBRE_DESTINATARIO>HOST ADMIRALE GORA</NOMBRE_DESTINATARIO>
<DIRECCION_DESTINATARIO>BBA 56 # 21 - 001</DIRECCION_DESTINATARIO>
<DANE_DESTINO>0200000</DANE_DESTINO>
<CIUDAD_DESTINO>GORA                           </CIUDAD_DESTINO>
<DEPARTAMENTO_DESTINO>ANTIOCHIA                          </DEPARTAMENTO_DESTINO>
<FECHA_ENTREGA>11/02/2020</FECHA_ENTREGA>
<HORA_ENTREGA>11:44</HORA_ENTREGA>
<FECHA_CITA />
<HORA_CITA />
<CODIGO_ESTADO>Z  </CODIGO_ESTADO>
<NOMBRE_ESTADO>CUMPLEANNO                      </NOMBRE_ESTADO>
<FECHA_ESTADO>11/01/2020</FECHA_ESTADO>
<HORA_ESTADO>11:44</HORA_ESTADO>
<CODIGO_NOVEDAD />
<NOMBRE_NOVEDAD />
<FECHA_NOVEDAD />
<HORA_NOVEDAD />
<COMENTARIO_NOVEDAD />
<OBSERVACIONES />
<ENLACE_IMAGEN>https://ssssss.ssssssss.com/SSSSSS/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.aspx?1111111,222222222,SIXA_XEOX,SIXAXEOX2016</ENLACE_IMAGEN>
<DOCUMENTO_2>169999999999</DOCUMENTO_2>
<DOCUMENTO_3 />
<DOCUMENTO_4 />
<FECHA_TRANSMISION>18/02/2020</FECHA_TRANSMISION>
<HORA_TRANSMISION>08:12:30</HORA_TRANSMISION>
<MENSAJE_TRANSMISION>KK</MENSAJE_TRANSMISION>
<PROMESA_SERVICIO>15/10/21</PROMESA_SERVICIO>
<CODIGO_DIVISION>011111</CODIGO_DIVISION>
<NOMBRE_DIVISION>ABDURREZZAK                    </NOMBRE_DIVISION>
</SDTDesperadosClientItem>
<SDTDesperadosClientItem xmlns="TrainsWebb_V16">
<AESA>10555555555        </AESA>
<DOCUMENTO>177777777</DOCUMENTO>
<REMITENTE>9999999999     </REMITENTE>
<NM_REMITENTE>ABDULREZZAK S.A.S.                        </NM_REMITENTE>
<FECHA_ELABORACION>12/8/2020</FECHA_ELABORACION>
<HORA_ELABORACION>16:27</HORA_ELABORACION>
<CODIGO_DEST>0000000000</CODIGO_DEST>
<NIT_DESTINATARIO>0000000000</NIT_DESTINATARIO>
<NOMBRE_DESTINATARIO>GORA FORA</NOMBRE_DESTINATARIO>
<DIRECCION_DESTINATARIO>BBG 16 # 91 - 021</DIRECCION_DESTINATARIO>
<DANE_DESTINO>0500000</DANE_DESTINO>
<CIUDAD_DESTINO>AROG                           </CIUDAD_DESTINO>
<DEPARTAMENTO_DESTINO>ANTIOCHIA                          </DEPARTAMENTO_DESTINO>
<FECHA_ENTREGA>10/02/2020</FECHA_ENTREGA>
<HORA_ENTREGA>10:44</HORA_ENTREGA>
<FECHA_CITA />
<HORA_CITA />
<CODIGO_ESTADO>D  </CODIGO_ESTADO>
<NOMBRE_ESTADO>CUMPLEANNI                      </NOMBRE_ESTADO>
<FECHA_ESTADO>11/01/2020</FECHA_ESTADO>
<HORA_ESTADO>11:44</HORA_ESTADO>
<CODIGO_NOVEDAD />
<NOMBRE_NOVEDAD />
<FECHA_NOVEDAD />
<HORA_NOVEDAD />
<COMENTARIO_NOVEDAD />
<OBSERVACIONES />
<ENLACE_IMAGEN>https://ssssss.ssssssss.com/SSSSSS/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.aspx?1111111,222222222,SIXA_XEOX,SIXAXEOX2016</ENLACE_IMAGEN>
<DOCUMENTO_2>1677777777</DOCUMENTO_2>
<DOCUMENTO_3 />
<DOCUMENTO_4 />
<FECHA_TRANSMISION>18/02/2020</FECHA_TRANSMISION>
<HORA_TRANSMISION>08:12:30</HORA_TRANSMISION>
<MENSAJE_TRANSMISION>HK</MENSAJE_TRANSMISION>
<PROMESA_SERVICIO>15/10/21</PROMESA_SERVICIO>
<CODIGO_DIVISION>011111</CODIGO_DIVISION>
<NOMBRE_DIVISION>ABDURREZZAK                    </NOMBRE_DIVISION>
</SDTDesperadosClientItem>
</Sdtdesperadosclient>
</Desperados_Clientes_V2.DESPERADOSResponse>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>"""


myroot = ET.fromstring(response)

for child in myroot.iter('*'):
    print(child.tag)
    
sid = myroot.findall(".//{'TrainsWebb_V16'}AESA")
print(sid)
```

Comment: What seems to be the problem? Are you getting errors? Unexpected results? Something else? Please update your question to include these details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For parsing into a pandas DataFrame, you can use the `pandas.read_xml` function:

```py
data_frame = pd.read_xml(response, xpath="//*[name()='SDTDesperadosClientItem']")
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_xml.html#pandas-read-xml

Comment: Thanks, i didn't know that attribute of pandas. My version was 1.2.4 so, when i updated my pandas version, i could turn it into a data frame as you suggested.